# WP 7.5 - Is LowProfileImageLoader still a best practice in Mango?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is it still a best practice to use the LowProfileImageLoader in Mango?

Comment: Not sure about best practice but using the BackgroundCreation image options it looks like this can be built more simply in 7.1 SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you read this article, and judge yourself: [Off-thread decoding of images on Mango, how it impacts your application ?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/13/off-thread-decoding-of-images-on-mango-how-it-impacts-you-application.aspx).

My personal experience says that the `BackgroundCreation` option is still doing way more work on the UI thread than the `LowProfileImageLoader`. I have some projects where it's still necessary.

Specially in combination with the `LongListSelector` (from the Silverlight Toolkit) and it's custom way of doing virtualization, I find the `LowProfileImageLoader` much needed to avoid having a second-second UI lock in one of my applications.